# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView on IOS without predictive text causes errors when changing keyboards

Tags: ios, react-native

When I disable predictive text on an IOS device keyboardAvoidingView no longer works when changing between the text keyboard and the emoji keyboard.

When you first focus on the textInput the keyboardAvoidingView works as expected, however if you then select the emoji keyboard option the keyboard avoiding view drops and the keyboard is covering the textInput.

Note this is only an issue on Apple devices when predictive text has been turned off in the settings.

Any suggestions on how to work around this would be great please.

Comment: Is predictive text being turned off manually via settings or programmatically? If the latter, can you provide some code as to how you are doing this?

Comment: It is when the user switches it off manually in their own settings.